# EasyMock returning null

Tags: java, easymock

I am currently working on some test cases which use `EasyMock`. My example code looks like this:

```
{
    dao = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Dao.class);

    initObj();
    EasyMock.replay(dao);
    // EasyMock.verify(dao);

    mapper = new Mapper();
    mapper.setDao(dao);
}
@Test
public void testmapper(){ 
    mapper.map();
}

public void initObj() {
    Obj o = new Obj();
    o.setX(2);
    EasyMock.expect(dao.findObj(1)).andReturn(o);
}

class Mapper {
    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    public Obj map(){
        Obj o = dao.findObj(1);
        System.out.println(o.getX());
        return o;
    }
    //getter and setter
}
```

if I actually call `EasyMock.verify(dao);`, it throws

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    dao.findObj(1): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.verify(MocksControl.java:183)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.verify(EasyMock.java:2142)
    ...
```

and if I don't call verify, my first call inside the `Mapper` class on my `Obj` results in an NPE. I am very new to EasyMock and could not yet find the reason why it is not returning the `Obj` I created in `initObj`. Any enlightenment is welcome. I read some question on SO to this topic as well as some simple tutorials, but they didn't help me

Comment: What is the signature of `Obj#findObj`? Is it with `Integer`? (Shouldn't cause a problem, because the first n `Integer` instances are cached, but who knows?)

Comment: `Obj#findObj` delivers an custom object from database. @khelwood because i didn't have the verify call in my code at first

Comment: the question wasn't targeted on the return type, but on the type of the argument...

Comment: ahh, i pass in an ID on which the obj will be searched. but in my understanding, `EasyMock.expect(dao.findObj(1)).andReturn(o);` waits for any call which looks like `dao.findObj(1)` and instead returns the object i defined in `andReturn(o);`

Comment: The provided Mapper class is not valid java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. In my `initObj()` method I also have to define the number of calls for the expected behavior like this:

```
public void initObj() {
    Obj o = new Obj();
    o.setX(2);
    EasyMock.expect(dao.findObj(1)).andReturn(o).times(1);
}
```

What I yet still don't understand how it can work without the `times(1)`. I have some example code from a co-worker where it works with simply using `EasyMock.expect(dao.findObj(1)).andReturn(o);`

Comment: No. You don't have to specify `times(1)`. By default EasyMock will count one call when calling `andReturn`

Comment: @Henri my exact problem was that i misunderstood the annotations `@Before` and `@After` as i thought they would be only called once and not before every test. also were not every method i specified as expected in my `@Before` called in every test and therefore the `EasyMock.verify(dao);` failed as well. however, i now have the code working and learned from my mistakes

Answer (score 1):

The `verify` should be after your test. So after the `mapper.map()`. It is used to verify that all expected calls were made. So it makes sense it occurs at the end.

Then, it is absolutely impossible to get an NPE with the code you are providing. Unless you have a problem with getX and setX. Here is my version of your code. It works perfectly.

```
public class MyTest {

    private final Dao dao;
    private final Mapper mapper;

    {
        dao = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Dao.class);

        initObj();
        EasyMock.replay(dao);
        // EasyMock.verify(dao);

        mapper = new Mapper();
        mapper.setDao(dao);
    }

    @Test
    public void testmapper(){
        mapper.map();
        EasyMock.verify(dao);
    }

    public void initObj() {
        Obj o = new Obj();
        o.setX(2);
        EasyMock.expect(dao.findObj(1)).andReturn(o);
    }

    class Mapper {
        private Dao dao;

        public Obj map(){
            Obj o = dao.findObj(1);
            System.out.println(o.getX());
            return o;
        }

        public void setDao(Dao dao) {
            this.dao = dao;
        }
    }

    class Obj {
        private int x;

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
    }

    interface Dao {
        Obj findObj(int i);
    }
}
```